# Marketing Cloud - Data encryption with AMPscript encrypt symmetric function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, encryption

I would like to encrypt subscriber's email address in SFMC during an email send and attach it to the URL. Once the user clicks on that URL, he gots redirected to the website where the encrypted email will be extracted and decrypted in order to understand who is viewing the page.

For email address encryption I'm using the *AMPscript's EncryptSymmetric function* with *des algorithm*, *cbc mode* and pass the Password and Initialization Vector. I have copied the example values for Password and Initialization Vector from the official documentation, and in SFMC I'm able to encrypt and decrypt data successfully.

However, on the website (and basically using any online decryption tool) using the same algorithm and mode, I'm not able to decrypt the previously encrypted emails. There are always errors saying that the encrypted strings are heavier or lighter (in terms of bytes) than needed.

Is there any advice on how should the values for the password and IV look like? Or maybe can you paste an example values (I'll keep the length but modify the content) that I can use?

Thank you in advance!